# Processing Excel spreadsheets using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, spreadsheet, python-3.11

I am new (between zero to basic) to Python but I love the simplicity of coding. Looking for help in following problem. Ton of thanks in advance

I have two spreadsheets

1. One containing a list of folder paths (delimiter - backslash) in single column - **Check spreadsheet**
2. Other containing 3 columns with productcode, wordslist, priority - **Master spreadsheet**

I am trying to write a Python code to scan all Check spreadsheets one at a time in a folder against the one Master spreadsheet. Here's sort of requirements I wrote for scanning one Check spreadsheet.

1. Read each cell from Check spreadsheet with option to read from right to left(RL)
2. Search each word into "wordslist" column (comma separated values in the cell) from Master spreadsheet
3. If found, save the code and priority and keep searching for the word until end of Master
4. From the search result, look for code with highest priority (1 has highest priority as compared to 2)
5. Add the highest priority code in the adjacent column of the cell in 'Check' spreadsheet
6. If not found, keep searching (R to L, L To R based on the option selected) for all words in the folder path from Check spreadsheet
7. If any of the words in the folder path are not found in Master, add 'TBD' to the adjacent column of the cell in 'Check' spreadsheet
8. Move to next cell and repeat steps from 1 to 7

Master spreadsheet contains data in 3 columns like :

| Productcode | wordslist | priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| prdX001 | folder 1 name, apple, orange, subfolder 2 name | 1 |
| prdX002 | folder 1 name, apple, folder 2 name, orange | 2 |
| prdX003 | subfolder 1 name, apple, orange, folder 2 name | 3 |
| prdX004 | apple, orange, folder 1 name, subfolder 2 name | 4 |

Check spreadsheet contains data like : reading from right to left

| TestValue | Code Applied | Reason (to understand not to be added to Check spreadsheet) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \\server\fileshare\folder 1 name\subfolder 1 name | 3 | (prdx004 doesn't apply priority is low) |
| \\server\fileshare\folder 2 name\subfolder 2 name | 1 |  |

I have 2 different programs, hoping to combine not sure how. Lack of experience at times is frustrating.

1. Pick up one cell from 'Check' spreadsheet

```py
# Loop will print all values of first column
for i in range(2, m_row + 1):
    cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 1)
    # print(cell_obj.value)
    path = os.path.normpath(cell_obj.value)
    split_path = path.split('\\')
    for x in range(len(split_path)):
        #Don't like this hard coding
        if x > 3:
            if len(split_path[x]) > 0:
                print(split_path[x])
```

2. Searching in Master spreadsheet

```py
# Read Excel file
df = pd.read_excel(path_universal,sheet_name=1, usecols=[1])
for value in df['wordslist']:
    # do something with value
    my_list = df['wordslist'].str.split(',')
    print(tuple(my_list))
```

Comment: Could you share what you've tried?

Comment: Please edit your question to format the code as code. SO help shows how.

Comment: @emmanuel Murairi
I tried 2 things -
1. Read the 'Check' worksheet in loop and split the read value in words to save it in a list.

2. Search that word in the 'Master' spreadsheet in another program.

I am sorry I am new to stackoverflow so must have jumbled up the code. But I promise you it is there in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following produces what you are looking for.  I have added to your initial code, so some of it is the same.

Some of the changes:

1. The whole of `df` is used (from the Master file), and it is easier to work with the whole dataframe than looping through each row and using the list.
2. I have changed the "hard-coded" conditional on the directory split.

Left-to-right or right-to-left and creation of Master file dataframe:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

LR = True  # if True then left-to-right, if False then right-to-left

# Searching in Master spreadsheet
# Read Excel file
path_universal = "Master.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(path_universal,sheet_name="Sheet1")
# split "wordslist" column and explode to separate rows
df["wordslist"] = df["wordslist"].str.split(",")
df = df.explode("wordslist")
# remove trailing and leading whitespaces
df["wordslist"] = df["wordslist"].str.strip()
```

The Check file:

```py
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Check.xlsx")
sheet_obj = wb["Sheet1"]
m_row = sheet_obj.max_row

# Pick up one cell from 'Check' spreadsheet
# Loop will print all values of first column
for i in range(2, m_row + 1):
    cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row=i, column=1)
    # print(cell_obj.value)
    path = os.path.normpath(cell_obj.value)
    # split, filter for not "", and reverse if LR==False
    split_path = list(filter(None, path.split("\\")))[::(1 if LR else -1)]
    code, priority = None, None
    for s in split_path:
        # filter df for matching with s
        df1 = df[df["wordslist"].eq(s)]
        # if no matches then df1 is empty, otherwise df1.empty is False
        if not df1.empty:
            (code, _, priority) = df1[df1["priority"].eq(df1["priority"].min())].iloc[0].values
            break  # stop after 1st match
    if not code:
        code, priority = "TBD", "TBD"  # "TBD" if no matches
    sheet_obj.cell(row=i, column=4).value = code
    sheet_obj.cell(row=i, column=5).value = priority
# add headers to new columns
sheet_obj.cell(row=1, column=4).value = "Master Code"
sheet_obj.cell(row=1, column=5).value = "Priority"

# save and close Check spreadsheet
wb.save("Check.xlsx")
wb.close()
```

Note: you will probably need to change the file names!

Comment: Absolutely loved your idea of removing the hard coding and going thru whole of Master in 'DF'. 

The way it is currently codes - do I have to run the 'Master' code first and then run the 'Check' code in same session. Is there anyway I can combine 2 programs, like some function? Not sure what constructs are available in Python. Once again ton of thanks for your help and guidance.

Comment: You definitely can!  One option might be to modularise the code - [this is a useful article about it] (https://towardsdatascience.com/mastering-modular-programming-how-to-take-your-python-skills-to-the-next-level-ba14339e8429).

Comment: A simple method would be to wrap the two sections of code as functions, e.g. `def master()` with `return df` at the end, and then `def checks(df)`, passing the required master dataframe as an input.